# Django Comments error following tutorial

Tags: django, django-templates, django-comments

I'm trying to integrate Django's comment app into my site but with no success. I've been following the documentation outlined at: [Django comments](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/comments/)

The error I'm getting is:

> Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried search in module FrontEnd.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'

nothing in my views refers to anything involving search. Something in the comments install is causing this. The line that actually fails is.

```
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
```

**comment_form_target** is highlighted.

The code  causing the error:

```
{% load comments %}
{% get_comment_form for article as form %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

From what I've found online, it looks like i'm either missing some library in my Python 2.7 or i'm doing circular imports?

Comment: That error occurs when you're trying to access a view that doesn't exist. What url are you using to access the page and what is the associated view show in urls.py?

Comment: The view without this block of code works fine. With this block it causes the error

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what the problem is. Can you try creating a search view in your FrontEnd.views.py file? Just to see what it's expecting?

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of that but it exposed the red herring. I was using Haystack search and "uninstalled" (clearly I missed something!) and thats whats causing the problems. Appreciated.

Comment: Yay! :P Glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a search view in `FrontEnd.views.py` and see what the problem is.

I'm adding an answer so we can nicely close this ticket.

An error of the form

> Tried test in module appname.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'

is generated when django tries to do reverse url lookups and the urls.py file contains a broken view.